# elasticsearch - Tag data with lookup table values

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, lookup, lookup-tables

I’m trying to tag my data according to a lookup table.
The lookup table has these fields:

• *Key*- represent the field name in the data I want to tag.
In the real data the field is a subfield of “Headers” field..
An example for the “Key” field:
“Server. (* is a wildcard)

• *Value*- represent the wanted value of the mentioned field above.
The value in the lookup table is only a part of a string in the real data value.
An example for the “Value” field:
“Avtech”.

• *Vendor*- the value I want to add to the real data if a combination of field- value is found in an document.

An example for combination in the real data:
“Headers.Server : Linux/2.x UPnP/1.0 Avtech/1.0”

```
A match with that document in the look up table will be:
Key= Server (with wildcard on both sides).
Value= Avtech(with wildcard on both sides)
Vendor= Avtech
```

So baisically I’ll need to add a field to that document with the value- “ Avtech”.

- the subfields in “Headers” are dynamic fields that changes from document to document.
- of a match is not found I’ll need to add to the tag field with value- “Unknown”.

I’ve tried to use the enrich processor , use the lookup table as the source data , the match field will be ”Value” and the enrich field will be “Vendor”.
In the enrich processor I didn’t know how to call to the field since it’s dynamic and I wanted to search if the value is anywhere in the “Headers” subfields.
Also, I don’t think that there will be a match between the “Value” in the lookup table and the value of the Headers subfield, since “Value” field in the lookup table is a substring with wildcards on both sides.

I can use some help to accomplish what I’m trying to do.. and how to search with wildcards inside an enrich processor.
or if you have other idea besides the enrich processor- such as parent- child and lookup terms mechanism.

Thanks!
Adi.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to accomplish this:

1. Using the combination of Logstash & Elasticsearch
2. Using the only the Elastichsearch Ingest node

**Constriant**: You need to know the position of the Vendor term occuring in the Header field.

**Approach 1**
If so then you can use the GROK filter to extract the term. And based on the term found, do a lookup to get the corresponding value.

**Reference**

1. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html
2. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-kv.html
3. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-jdbc_static.html
4. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-jdbc_streaming.html

**Approach 2**
Create an index consisting of KV pairs. In the ingest node, create a pipeline which consists of Grok processor and then Enrich it. The Grok would work the same way mentioned in the Approach 1. And you seem to have already got the Enrich part working.

**Reference**

1. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/grok-processor.html

If you are able to isolate the sub field within the Header where the Term of interest is present then it would make things easier for you.